# How to remove file from hole git tree, that has already been deleted from disk

Tags: git, github

I've tried to push data to github, but got error

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 175fa38dfe7c67becde0232ae3469018
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Pods/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.framework/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel is 302.51 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/paulo-bellator/MoneyFlow.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/paulo-bellator/MoneyFlow.git'
```

I deleted the whole pod (by reinstalling pods), in which that file was. And tried again. 
Same error.

I tried

```
git rm --cached "myFilePath"
```

but file wasn't found.

```
fatal: pathspec 'Pods/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.framework/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel' did not match any files
```

I also tried

```
git commit --amend -CHEAD
```

Get this response. Then trying to push, but again got same error

```
MacBook-Air-Nikita:MoneyFlow nikitagoncharov$ git commit --amend -CHEAD
[master 65e9e7a] remove MLVisionTextRecognizing model
 Date: Wed Oct 9 13:57:22 2019 +0300
 30 files changed, 2965 insertions(+), 4612 deletions(-)
```

Finally tried this command, but nothing happened.

```
git filter-branch
```

So i'm still getting this error, and can't push my data.

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected
```

What should i do to remove this file from git, and finally push my data into github?

Comment: When exactly (in terms of git history) this file was added? Is it in the latest commit?

Comment: @sbat  'Wed Oct 9 13:57:22 2019 +0300 remove MLVisionTextRecognizing model

Comment: @sbat 'Sun Sep 29 00:47:50 2019 +0300 add VisionTextRecognizer to parse ops from screens'

Comment: @sbat i added this file on another branch, and stay there for a long time. Few days ago, i merged that branch into master. And trying to push master, but it fails

Comment: In that case I'd second the suggestion above to use filter-branch. You need to change all your new commits and remove this large file from each one of them. Question linked above by @LasseVågsætherKarlsen should cover this. Just make sure you pass your original commit with this particular file to it (not --all) to make sure you only change your new commits (just in case). Backing up entire repo before that is good idea.

Comment: @sbat, thanks! I've solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

There are lot of answers there and most of them are extremely complicated for me (i'm newbie with git), but this solution seemed me simple and it's worked perfect!

Solution:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f file-to-be-removed-name' HEAD
```